# JSON data to javascript Array Android browser .length gives wrong value

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON DATA from URL:

```
[ { "url": "http://google.com" }, { "url":"http://yahoo.com" } ]
```

This will bring a list of URLS

```
jsOnData.push(xhr.response);
```

`jsOnData.length` will return 1
`jsOnData[0][0].url` will return first url
`jsOnData[0].length` will return 2
but in Android 4.4.4 Default browser it is abnormal value and it is not working as expected. In Desktop browser and Mobile Chrome, Opera, Firefox it is working as expected. But Android browser, UC WEB, Dolphin it is not working and also retuning same abnormal value.

Abnormal value: 101 (on Android browser, UC WEB & Dolphin)

Which is the best way to get list of urls from JSON file and Parse it to normal JavaScript Array?

Comment: And you forgot to say what's that abnormal result......

Comment: it is 101 @MatíasFidemraizer

Comment: Uhm, 101... are you sure? ...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer yes in all 3 browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what JSON is. JSON is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you want is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different.

It seems like whatever you are using to make the HTTP request is auto parsing the JSON response into a POJO on some browsers and not on others.

```
var json = '[{"url":"http://google.com"},{"url":"http://yahoo.com"}]';
json.length // 56 (this is the character count since json is a string)
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.length // 2 (since there are two items in the array
obj[0].url // 'http://google.com'
```

UPDATE: after discussion with OP, his issue was lack of support for `responseType` in his `XMLHttpRequest` handler (it's a level 2 enhancement where as the browsers in question only support level 1). Added the following check to see if the response was auto-parsed to an object and if not do it manually:

`var obj = typeof xhr.response === 'string' ? JSON.parse(xhr.response) : xhr.response;`

Comment: when i try to parse i am getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: `JSON.parse` expects a string not an object. Is this is on the browsers getting the odd results? Did you post the entire returned object?

Comment: This is what i have on my JSON file [
{
"url": "http://google.com"
},
{
"url": "http://yahoo.com"
}
]

Comment: But what is returned to the browser? Can you log out the entire object. Also note that is invalid JSON. You can't have semicolons where you have them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75053/discussion-between-vishnu-and-jason-cust).

Answer (score -1):

Use concat instead of push, because you add one array to another